# CSS & HTML : my margin is not exactly ending at the left border

Tags: html, css

Good day,

In my web page designed for smartphones, I have added a footer as shown in the screenshot and in the extracted html code below (I have extracted the relevant part of the code in order to avoid to annoy you). I am trying to have the blue ribbon extended up to the left hand side margin.

Any idea what I am missing here ?

Many thanks for your help. Happy Easter Monday.

[image]

HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
...
    <div class="footer" id="footer">Domoosweb mobile version 0.0.1    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS code :

```
#tag_domoos_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 130px;
    color:blue;
    z-index:10;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#tag_update{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 90px;
    color:blue;
}

#datetime{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 130px;
    color:blue;
}

#tag_sunrise_sunset{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    color:black;
}

#tag_weather_temperature{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 145px;
    right: 15px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#current_weather_conditions_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 95%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 10px;
    color:blue;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#current_weather_forecast_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 95%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 10px;
    color:blue;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#tag_weather_condition{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#tag_additional_weather_information{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 100px;
}

#meteo_forecast{
    font-family:Arial;  
    font-size: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height:434px;
    width:870px;
    top:200px;
    position: relative;
}

#meteo_forecast_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 215px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 285px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 355px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 215px;
    right: 5px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 285px;
    right: 5px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 355px;
    right: 5px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 235px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 305px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 375px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#domoos_logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0px;
}

#lorem{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 10px;
    height: auto;
}

#footer
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 40%;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px groove #aaaaaa;
    background: blue;
    color: White;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#hyperlinks_mobile
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

ul {
  background: #bbb;
}
li, [class*="grid"] > * {
  background: #ccc;
}
header, footer {
  background: #ddd;
}
body {
    background-color:#ddd;
}
progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;

   /* leave defaults in for other browsers */
   background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
   color:purple; 
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Check the Dev Tools as to what is causing the space, using the Dev Tools will help you in the long run

Comment: @Tesseract, thanks. Do you know how I could achieve this in Notepad++?

Comment: The dev tools built in the browser, like Chrome. Press F12 to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `left:0;` to `#footer`. See the following (minimized) solution:

```css
#footer {
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size: 40%;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px groove #aaaaaa;
  background: blue;
  color: White;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="footer" id="footer">Domoosweb mobile version 0.0.1</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Just update your `#footer` CSS with following CSS

```
#footer { 
    left: 0; 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the default value for the body is causing you problems. Different browsers have different default values for certain things. Try a reset of the body declarations by putting this on line 1 of your css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, the default margin is 8px.

If you want to change it, you can just do this:

1) Set `left: 0px` at #footer

```
#footer
{
    ...
    left:0px;        /* add this line */
}
```

or

2) Set `margin: 0px` at body

```
body {
    background-color:#ddd;
    margin: 0px;     /* add this line */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the default margin :)

Answer (score 1):

As per your `HTML` and `CSS` codes `#footer` is `positioned` as `fixed`,

> Position - fixed - Do not leave space for the element. Instead,
>   position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport
>   and don't move it when scrolled.

So whenever a element is position as `fixed` or `absolute`, you will often find some spacing at `left side`, that's because when elements are positioned like this there `top, left, right and bottom` values are initialized as `auto`, so easy fix is to check if you have added `margin:0` to `body` or add `left` as `0`.

```css
#footer{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 40%;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px groove #aaaaaa;
    background: blue;
    color: White;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer" id="footer">Domoosweb mobile version 0.0.1 </div>
```

**Or**

```css
body{
margin:0;
}
#footer{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 40%;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px groove #aaaaaa;
    background: blue;
    color: White;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer" id="footer">Domoosweb mobile version 0.0.1 </div>
```